# Embed multiple jpeg images into EXCEL programmatically?

Tags: java, python, ruby, image, excel

Dear Stackoverflowers,

Outputting an Excel spreadsheet with images is a requirement of a project I'm doing. I've done a little research and found the following (perhaps incorrect) consensus :

- various python libs for creating excels sheets work well
- it is possible to insert images (but only in bmp)
- the "internal format" of images used in excel files, is complicated, which may be why there is no 3rd party library support for inserting normal formats like jpeg.

I don't want to use or convert to bmp. Why? BMP are not compressed well, and these will be **big** sheets, so I want to mitigate the size impact of images (1 per row) as much as possible.

My ideal answer comes from someone who has actually done this. The method suggested can be in Java,Ruby,Python,(but not .NET) or some other creative way of doing it.

I'm really hoping someone out there has a solution, as I anticipate this could be a tricky area (similar in complexity to playing around with PDFs, perhaps).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you given a look to the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, just done some research and feel it could be tricky. Looking for reassurance from someone with experience. That's great, perfect I think. I'm satisfied with that if you want to make it an answer.

Comment: Spreadsheets are for text and numbers, not images. You should reconsider if Excel is really the right tool for this job.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, I reconsidered and -- sometimes a spreadsheet is the best way to put everything in one place. The columns of a table are usually metrics against a set of objects (the rows), no? An image is just another metric, a particularly handy one if you need something visual to get a reference point! And in this case, the spreadsheet was also appropriate for the following reasons : 1) the end user asked for it, 2) the user's primary purpose of the data collected is to analyze it using Excel, 3) each row has associated image which the end users asked to be included with the data.

Comment: I disagree. Excel can set images as backgrounds for individual cells. Don't confuse this for a 'metric'.

Comment: @pguardiario Can it also put images in cells, so the cell becomes sized as per the image? Like a HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment above, [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can solve your problem.

I did a little research and this example should be useful [Apache POI Excel Insert an Image](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/apache-poi-excel-insert-image.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Perl module [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm) can insert [JPEG, PNG, and BMP images](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#insert_image%28_%24row,_%24col,_%24filename,_%24x,_%24y,_%24x_scale,_%24y_scale_%29) into a new Excel workbook.

I am currently porting it to a Python module called [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and the `inset_image()` function is near the top of the TODO list.

**Update**: As of version 0.1.6 of XlsxWriter it is now possible to a add PNG/JPEG images. See [the example in the documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_images.html).