# Writing pandas/matplotlib image directly into XLSX file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, xlsxwriter

I am generating plots in pandas/matplotlib and wish to write them to an XLSX file. I am not looking to create native Excel charts; I am merely writing the plots as non-interactive images. I am using the [XlsxWriter library/engine](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/).

The closest solution I have found is [the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907210/insert-pandas-chart-into-an-excel-file-using-xlsxwriter), which suggests using the [XlsxWriter.write_image()](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-insert-image) method. However, this method appears to take a filename as its input. I am trying to programmatically pass the direct output from a pandas/matplotlib `plot()` call, e.g. something like this:

```
h = results.resid.hist()
worksheet.insert_image(row, 0, h) # doesn't work
```

or this:

```
s = df.plot(kind="scatter", x="some_x_variable", y="resid")
worksheet.insert_image(row, 0, s) # doesn't work
```

Is there any way to accomplish this, short of the workaround of writing the image to a disk file first?

## Update

Answer below got me on the right track and am accepting. I needed to make a few changes, mainly (I think) because I am using Python 3 and perhaps some API changes. Here is the solution:

```
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imgdata = BytesIO()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
results.resid.hist(ax=ax)
fig.savefig(imgdata, format="png")
imgdata.seek(0)

worksheet.insert_image(
    row, 0, "",
    {'image_data': imgdata}
)
```

The `""` in the `insert_image()` code is to trick Excel, which is still expecting a filename/URL/etc.

Comment: Quote: *The "" in the insert_image() code is to trick the API, which is still expecting a filename/URL/etc.* Strictly speaking, it is Excel that is expecting a filename, and for consistency it would be best to supply one.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why are you using matplotlib in this case and not adding a chart to the worksheet directly?

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that.  Re 2nd comment, the reason is that I am not exporting the data that would build the charts, just some different data and the plots themselves:  basically regression result summary and a whole lot of diagnostic plots like normal histogram of resids, QQ, scatters vs. resids, etc.  This is all for diagnostic purposes, not final business report.

Comment: This inserts a static image, not a real Plot - kind of a crummy version of a real Excel sheet.  Any way to insert a "real" graph (with editable axes etc)?

Comment: Yup that's why my question says " I am not looking to create native Excel charts; I am merely writing the plots as non-interactive images."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save the image to memory as a file object (not to disk) and then use that when inserting to Excel file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cStringIO import StringIO
imgdata = StringIO()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Make your plot here referencing ax created before
results.resid.hist(ax=ax)

fig.savefig(imgdata)

worksheet.insert_image(row, 0, imgdata)
```

Comment: StringIO is gone from Python 3. Any suggestions on how to make this work in Python 3?

Comment: In python 3 `StringIO` and `BytesIO` are in the builtin `io` module. Please have a look at the updated OP's question with example.