# Exporting a matplotlib chart directly to Excel? Without saving to file first

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write a matplotlib image directly into an Excel file using xlsx writer - ideally without saving the file to the disk.

I have found this answer: [Writing pandas/matplotlib image directly into XLSX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716911/writing-pandas-matplotlib-image-directly-into-xlsx-file) but I cannot get it to work, especially not with Python 3.

This: `wks1.insert_image(2,2, imgdata` doesn't work, because:

> path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.BytesIO

This: `wks1.insert_image(2,2,"",{'image data': imgdata}`)
gives a warning

> Image file '' not found.

and produces an excel file with no chart.

What does work is saving the file locally - but I'd like to understand if there's a way to avoid it.

```
fig.savefig('test.png', format='png')
wks1.insert_image(2,2, 'test.png')
```

Thoughts? The full code is:

```
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y=x**2

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test chart.xlsx')
wks1=workbook.add_worksheet('Test chart')
wks1.write(0,0,'test')

imgdata=io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')

wks1.insert_image(2,2,"",{'image data': imgdata})
#wks1.insert_image(2,2, imgdata)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: since the linked question contains the answer to the present question (see the part **Update**), this could probably be closed as a duplicate

Comment: yes - to be fair, it could be removed altogether

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) (and the link to the question you provided), the correct spelling for the optional argument to be passed to `insert_image` is `image_data` (noting the underscore _)

```
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y=x**2

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test chart.xlsx')
wks1=workbook.add_worksheet('Test chart')
wks1.write(0,0,'test')

imgdata=io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
wks1.insert_image(2,2, '', {'image_data': imgdata})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Can this be replicated to an existing excel document? And can we specify the sheetname?