# Putting multiple matplotlib graphs into Excel using Python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, matplotlib, openpyxl

I am trying to create some graphs based on a dataframe I have in Python 3 called back and export them into Excel. I have been using some of the code from the below response response, but when I use it for more than one graph it gives me some weird results:

[Can I insert matplotlib graphs into Excel programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177705/can-i-insert-matplotlib-graphs-into-excel-programmatically)

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import openpyxl

filepath = 'C:\Filepath\Template.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter')
back.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')
writer.save()

## PLOTS
## ts1 is company 1 and ts2 is company 2
def plot_results(df, ts1, ts2, filepath, cell):
    months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(df['price_date'], df[ts1], label=ts1)
    ax.plot(df['price_date'], df[ts2], label=ts2)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y'))
#    ax.set_xlim(datetime.datetime(start_year, start_month_num, start_day_num), datetime.datetime(end_year, end_month_num, end_day_num))
    ax.grid(True)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    plt.xlabel('Month/Year')
    plt.ylabel('Cumulative Percent Growth')
    plt.title('%s and %s Cumulative Percent Growth' % (ts1, ts2))
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=150)

    plt.show()

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    ws = wb.active    
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('plot.png')
    img.anchor(ws.cell(cell))
    ws.add_image(img)
    wb.save(filepath)

def plot_scatter_ts(df, ts1, ts2, filepath, cell):
    plt.xlabel('%s Price ($)' % ts1)
    plt.ylabel('%s Price ($)' % ts2)
    plt.title('%s and %s Price Scatterplot' % (ts1, ts2))
    plt.scatter(df[ts1], df[ts2])

    plt.show()

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    ws = wb.active
    plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=150)    
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('plot.png')
    img.anchor(ws.cell(cell))
    ws.add_image(img)
    wb.save(filepath)

plot_results(back, 'adj_close_price4.0', 'adj_close_price26.0', filepath, 'P2')
plot_scatter_ts(back, 'adj_close_price4.0', 'adj_close_price26.0', filepath, 'P34')
```

When I run the functions `plot_reults` or `plot_scatter_ts` by themselves they run and go into Excel fine. But if I run them together only the graph run last ends up in the Excel document, so in this case the scatter plot. Furthermore I don't really want to see the graphs in the Python interface so if I get rid of the `plt.show()` in the `plot_results` function the scatter plot for some reason becomes a bar graph, which is weird as neither of those graphs are bar graphs and they are in different functions.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Update 13/6/18

Sorry been a bit busy didn't have a chance to get back to this.

As suggested I have rewritten my code using  Pandas xlsxwriter as Screenpaver suggested. But when I try to do more than one plot it still seems to muddle the plots. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import openpyxl

filepath = 'C:\...\Template.xlsx'


## Chart 1

def plot_results(df, ts1, ts2, sheet_name, filepath, cell):

    ## Create Pandas Excel writer using Xlswriter as the engine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter')
    back.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, startcol=1)

    ## Access the Xlswriter workbook and worksheets objects from the dataframe.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    ## Create a chart object 
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'line'})

    ## Calculate extremes for axes
    min_x1 = back[ts1].min()
    max_x1 = back[ts1].max()
    min_x2 = back[ts2].min()
    max_x2 = back[ts2].max()    
    min_x = min(min_x1, min_x2)
    max_x = max(max_x1, max_x2)


    ## Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data
    chart.add_series({
            'name':ts1,
            'categories': '=test!$D$3:$D502',
            'values':'=test!$C$3:$C502'
            })

    chart.add_series({
            'name':ts2,
            'categories': '=test!$D$3:$D502',
            'values':'=test!$E$3:$E502'
            })

    ## Configure chart axis
    chart.set_x_axis({'name':'Month/Year',
                      'date_axis':True,
                      'num_format': 'mm/yy', 
                      'major_gridlines':{
                              'visible':True,
                              'line':{'width':1, 'dash_type':'dash'}
                              }})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name':'Cumulative Percent Growth',
                      'min':min_x,
                      'max':max_x,
                      'major_gridlines':{
                              'visible':True,
                              'line':{'width':1, 'dash_type':'dash'}
                              }                  
                      })
    chart.set_title({'name':'%s and %s Cumulative Percent Growth' % (ts1, ts2)})

    chart.set_legend({'position':'bottom'})
    chart.set_chartarea({'border':{'none':True}})

    ## Insert chart into worksheet
    worksheet.insert_chart(cell, chart)

    writer.save()




## Chart 2
def plot_scatter_ts(df, ts1, ts2, sheet_name, filepath, cell):

    ## Create Pandas Excel writer using Xlswriter as the engine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter')
    back.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, startcol=1)

    ## Access the Xlswriter workbook and worksheets objects from the dataframe.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]


    ## Create a chart object 
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'scatter'})


    min_x1 = back[ts1].min()
    max_x1 = back[ts1].max()
    min_x2 = back[ts2].min()
    max_x2 = back[ts2].max()    

    ## Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data
    chart.add_series({
            #        'name':'Series1',
            'categories': 'test!$E$3:$E502',
            'values':'=test!$C$3:$C502'
            })


    ## Configure chart axis
    chart.set_x_axis({'name':ts1,
                          'min':min_x2,
                          'max':max_x2})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name':ts2,
                          'min':min_x1,
                          'max':max_x1})

    chart.set_title({'name':'%s and %s Price Scatterplot' % (ts1, ts2)})

    chart.set_legend({'none':True})
    chart.set_chartarea({'border':{'none':True}})

    ## Insert chart into worksheet
    worksheet.insert_chart(cell, chart)

    writer.save()

plot_scatter_ts(back, 'adj_close_price4.0', 'adj_close_price26.0', 'test2', filepath, 'Q18')

plot_results(back, 'series1', 'series2', 'test2', filepath, 'Q2')
```

Individually when run with the other commented out each of the function turns out fine but when I run both functions I get a single jumbled graph.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at using the Pandas xlsxwriter interface (chart.add_series, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks screenpaver, I have added an update above which uses xlswriter, but the graphs are still jumbling up when running both functions.

Comment: Doesn't the second function overwrite the spreadsheet created by the first function?  It seems you would want to create and pass 'writer' outside the functions and then use writer.save() after the second function call returns.

Comment: Thanks screenpaver that got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks screenpaver got it working by moving write out of the functions like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import openpyxl

filepath = 'C:\...\Template.xlsx'
sheet_name='test'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter')

## Chart 1

def plot_results(writer, df, ts1, ts2, sheet_name, filepath, cell):

    ## Create Pandas Excel writer using Xlswriter as the engine
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, startcol=1)

    ## Access the Xlswriter workbook and worksheets objects from the dataframe.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    ## Create a chart object 
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'line'})

    ## Calculate extremes for axes
    min_x1 = df[ts1].min()
    max_x1 = df[ts1].max()
    min_x2 = df[ts2].min()
    max_x2 = df[ts2].max()    
    min_x = min(min_x1, min_x2)
    max_x = max(max_x1, max_x2)


    ## Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data
    chart.add_series({
            'name':ts1,
            'categories': '=test!$D$3:$D502',
            'values':'=test!$C$3:$C502'
            })

    chart.add_series({
            'name':ts2,
            'categories': '=test!$D$3:$D502',
            'values':'=test!$E$3:$E502'
            })

    ## Configure chart axis
    chart.set_x_axis({'name':'Month/Year',
                      'date_axis':True,
                      'num_format': 'mm/yy', 
                      'major_gridlines':{
                              'visible':True,
                              'line':{'width':1, 'dash_type':'dash'}
                              }})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name':'Cumulative Percent Growth',
                      'min':min_x,
                      'max':max_x,
                      'major_gridlines':{
                              'visible':True,
                              'line':{'width':1, 'dash_type':'dash'}
                              }                  
                      })
    chart.set_title({'name':'%s and %s Cumulative Percent Growth' % (ts1, ts2)})

    chart.set_legend({'position':'bottom'})
    chart.set_chartarea({'border':{'none':True}})

    ## Insert chart into worksheet
    worksheet.insert_chart(cell, chart)





## Chart 2
def plot_scatter_ts(writer, df, ts1, ts2, sheet_name, filepath, cell):

    ## Create Pandas Excel writer using Xlswriter as the engine
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, startcol=1)

    ## Access the Xlswriter workbook and worksheets objects from the dataframe.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]


    ## Create a chart object 
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'scatter'})


    min_x1 = df[ts1].min()
    max_x1 = df[ts1].max()
    min_x2 = df[ts2].min()
    max_x2 = df[ts2].max()    

    ## Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data
    chart.add_series({
            #        'name':'Series1',
            'categories': 'test!$E$3:$E502',
            'values':'=test!$C$3:$C502'
            })


    ## Configure chart axis
    chart.set_x_axis({'name':ts1,
                          'min':min_x2,
                          'max':max_x2})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name':ts2,
                          'min':min_x1,
                          'max':max_x1})

    chart.set_title({'name':'%s and %s Price Scatterplot' % (ts1, ts2)})

    chart.set_legend({'none':True})
    chart.set_chartarea({'border':{'none':True}})

    ## Insert chart into worksheet
    worksheet.insert_chart(cell, chart)




plot_scatter_ts(writer, back, 'series1', 'series2', sheet_name, filepath, 'Q18')

plot_results(writer, back, 'series1', 'series2', sheet_name, filepath, 'Q2')

writer.save()
```