# insert plot from pandas to excel file

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

How can I add the plot of pandas to the second worksheet,I checked [Putting multiple matplotlib graphs into Excel using Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694835/putting-multiple-matplotlib-graphs-into-excel-using-python-3), but they use a different module to write to the excel file. everything is working in code(the bars shows correct output), I just want to add the plot to `graph1` sheet.
here is my code so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
#some code
ordered_list = csv_columns
wb=Workbook("New File.xlsx")
ws=wb.add_worksheet("New Sheet")
first_row=0
for header in ordered_list:
    col=ordered_list.index(header)
    ws.write(first_row,col,header)
row=1
for product in spider.found_items:
    for _key,_value in product.items():
        col=ordered_list.index(_key)
        ws.write(row,col,_value)
    row+=1
ws=wb.add_worksheet("graph1")
df = pd.DataFrame(spider.found_items)
counts =df.groupby('Merchant 1')['Merchant 1'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
counts.plot(kind='bar')
#counts.plot(kind='bar')
#add to second worksheet (graph1)
wb.close()
```

Comment: Save the plot as an image (.png) using `plt.save()`. Then add a shape to your Excel file (I'm assuming xlsxwriter can do this?) and set the background of the shape to your image. Do not add an image to your Excel file, add a shape. iirc, adding an image in Excel creates a reference to the image on your harddrive, whereas setting the background of a shape to an image actually embeds the image in your xlsx file.

Comment: @Dan it doesn't have an insert shape, only insert_image. but your Idea is what I am going to do it seems the only way

Comment: I would test that this works on a computer that does not have network access (or local access) to the original image file. In my experience, this will look fine on your computer but when you view the spreadsheet off the network the image will be broken. Maybe consider a different library? https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/api/openpyxl.drawing.shapes.html

Comment: you are right it doesn't work on other computers(outside network),I guess I have to rewrite using this module

Comment: Yeah, it's a really weird quirk of Excel. I found this out only after sending a broken chart to clients for months :( btw, I haven't used openpyxl, so I'm not recommending it specifically. I'm just saying look around at alternatives to see if there is one that can create shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I'd suggest creating a pandas/matplotlib graph, save the image and insert it to excel using `openpyxl` and `Pillow`.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def create_graph():
    # create your image, then save it as a .png file
    # You could use matplotlib
    plt.savefig("picture.png", dpi=600)

    

create_graph()
img = Image('picture.png')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Template.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb["Sheet"]
ws.add_image(img, 'A1')
wb.save("Template_modified.xlsx")
```