# How to export a chart from Google Colab to Excel

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I have a chart that was created by an output in Google Colab, I want to export it to Excel, is there a way to do it. Do I have to download it or something, here is a picture:
[image]

Note: I am getting started with data-science and am following a tutorial

Comment: If your goal is to just get the image into excel, I would suggest that yes, the easiest thing is to copy and paste.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the input, my goal is the get the image into excel, all the data I can download in CSV format, I know how to do that. Are there any more methods that you are aware of to get the image other than Copy-Paste?

Comment: @Mr. T Yes, thank you. The did answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Can I insert matplotlib graphs into Excel programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177705/can-i-insert-matplotlib-graphs-into-excel-programmatically)

Comment: For these cases, SO has [the duplicate flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: It looks pretty similar to me.

Comment: That is what I am saying. In these cases, you should raise the duplicate flag (underneath the question), not post a link as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.T Ok, Thanks.